# Firestore database model for Notion-like modules

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Notion.so features really nice modular blocks that can hold many different types of content, including other modular blocks. Everything that is typed, inserted, or edited is auto-saved and updated in realtime to other collaborators.

I got to thinking about what the best way to model the same recursively modular blocks in Firestore/NoSQL would be?

I would think that creating a block that holds references to other blocks would be the way to go. But I didn't know how that would impact performance with the extra roundtrips for querying the unknown number of references. On the other hand, storing data via duplication/denormalization that can be extremely deeply nested seems also problematic.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see more pros and cons regarding this topic.

Comment: @Brandon  Do you find the answer for your original question?

Comment: @AleksandrSkobeltcyn Unfortunately not. I didn't get a clear answer from the other SO questions. The supposed duplicate question includes a great answer on general considerations for NoSQL db design, but I didn't feel it answered the 'recursive modular blocks' aspect of this question. ‍♂️